# Relay JS only on client side

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I have developed a graphql server with laravel (https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql). Now I would like to create a React application by using Relay. When I create my first component, then I receive the error: 
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `Relay.QL`.

I still googled the error and I recognized that I need to install the Babel Relay Plugin. But to include this plugin I have to specify a schema. But I still have specified this schema on server side, why do I need this also in client side? Is there any example how to implement this when a server is still implemented (external server, e.g. no NodeJS server).

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema for your data on the server-side is required  by *babel-relay-plugin* to do transpilation of Relay.QL fragments in Javscripts that will be delivered to the client-side. However, note that on your GraphQL server, you define the schema in Laravel GraphQL PHP classes, which you need to convert it into JSON format that `babel-relay-plugin` expects.

For example, I did a similar setup with Rails and *graphql-ruby* (https://github.com/nethsix/relay-on-rails).

- Define the data schema on my server-side using *graphql-ruby* classes in `app/graph` directory
- Convert the schema into a JSON file using a script `lib/tasks/graphql.rake`, which I then stash into `app/assets/javascripts/relay/data/schema.json`
- Point to the `schema.json` in your `babelRelayPlug.js` file wherever it is (mine is in `assets/javascripts/relay/utils/babelRelayPlugin.js`)

For Rails, we can easily dump the `graphql-ruby` schema to json by just calling `#to_json` method.  You may have similar methods in PHP.

I compared the difference between setting up Relay on a nodejs server, vs. a non-nodejs server using an illustration here if it helps (https://medium.com/@khor/relay-facebook-on-rails-8b4af2057152)

Comment: This is a great answer. An alternative is to query your server for the schema (GraphQL supports introspection). Here's an example of how to do that: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/206#issuecomment-138186103.